# Make a dataframe with grouped questions from three columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following dataframe:

```
       A               B                  C
  I am motivated     Agree                4
  I am motivated     Strongly Agree       5
  I am motivated     Disagree             6
  I am open-minded   Agree                4
  I am open-minded   Disagree             4
  I am open-minded   Strongly Disagree    3
```

Where column A is the question, column B is the answer, and column C is the frequency of "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", and "Strongly Disagree" for the questions in column A.

How can I convert it into the following dataframe?

```
                  Strongly Agree    Agree     Disagree   Strongly Disagree
I am motivated        5               4           6             0
I am open-minded      0               4           4             3
```

I tried looking at groupby() for columns from other posts but could not figure it out.  Using python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because these are already frequency counts, we can assume that we have unique `Question` / `Opinion` pairs.  So, we can use `set_index` and `unstack` as there won't be a need to aggregate.  This should save us some time with efficiency.  We could accomplish the same goal with `pivot`, however, `pivot` doesn't have a `fill_value` option that enables us to preserve `dtype`

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack(fill_value=0)

B                 Agree  Disagree  Strongly Agree  Strongly Disagree
A                                                                   
I am motivated        4         6               5                  0
I am open-minded      4         4               0                  3
```

---

***Extra Credit***
*Turn `'B'` into a [**`pd.Categorical`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) and the columns will be sorted*

```
df.B = pd.Categorical(
    df.B, ['Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly Agree'], True)
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack(fill_value=0)

B                 Strongly Disagree  Disagree  Agree  Strongly Agree
A                                                                   
I am motivated                    0         6      4               5
I am open-minded                  3         4      4               0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also including in extra credit, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Use [DataFrame.pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [250]: df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[250]:
B                 Agree  Disagree  Strongly Agree  Strongly Disagree
A
I am motivated        4         6               5                  0
I am open-minded      4         4               0                  3
```